# Huawei Wallet Kit - tokens, keys - where to get?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, wallet, card

Using the Wallet Kit documentation, I still could not understand what keys and names to use. As an example - I'm using demo https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-wallet-clientdemo-android.

Where can I get the following parameters?

```
Constant.PRIVATE_KEY ?
Constant.PRIVATE_KEY_RUSSIA_RELEASE ?
passBuilder.setPassStyleIdentifier(styleId); (styleId)?
jsonObject.put("iss", issuerId); (issuerId)?
```

The demo with the original set of parameters works. Loyalty card is added successfully. But changing to my parameters, card is not added and I see an error message (failed to add, try again later). I guess I'm using the wrong set of parameters.